# Zend_Service_Twitter - Make API v1.1 ready

Tags: php, zend-framework, twitter, twitter-oauth

The Zend_Service_Twitter component is still for Twitters API v1.0 which will be deprecated at 5th March 2013. So I wanted to make my new website with Twitter API interaction v1.1 ready. 
Everything works fine with v1.0 but if I change the URL from `/1/` to `/1.1/` it fails with the HTTP header code 400 and the JSON error message: `Bad Authentication data` (Code: 215)

To get the request and access token stayed the same and works already without any changes,
but if I want to verify the credentials like this I get the error I described above:

```
// Take a look for the code here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.oauth.introduction.html
$accessToken = $twitterAuth->getAccessToken($_GET, unserialize($_SESSION['TWITTER_REQUEST_TOKEN']));


// I have a valid access token and now the problematic part
$twitter = new Zend_Service_Twitter(array(
    'username' => $accessToken->getParam('screen_name'),
    'accessToken' => $accessToken
));
print_r($twitter->account->verifyCredentials());
```

I changed the code of verifyCredentials in `Zend/Service/Twitter.php` from that to that:

```
public function accountVerifyCredentials()
{
    $this->_init();
    $response = $this->_get('/1/account/verify_credentials.xml');
    return new Zend_Rest_Client_Result($response->getBody());
}

// to

public function accountVerifyCredentials()
{
    $this->_init();
    $response = $this->_get('/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json');
    return Zend_Json::decode($response->getBody());
}
```

Now I added before the `return Zend_Json[...]` this line:

```
print_r($this->_localHttpClient->getLastRequest());

// And I get this output of it:

GET /1.1/account/verify_credentials.json HTTP/1.1
Host: api.twitter.com
Connection: close
Accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Zend_Http_Client
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8
Authorization: OAuth realm="",oauth_consumer_key="",oauth_nonce="91b6160db351060cdf4c774c78e2d0f2",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1349107209",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_token="hereismytoken",oauth_signature="hereisavalidsignature"
```

As you could see the `oauth_consumer_key` (and `realm` too) is empty. Could that be the error? How could I solve this error (because of the stricter new API version?)? Would it be fine to set somehow the `oauth_consumer_key`? If yes, how could I manage that?

Edit:
I also found already a bug report on the issue tracker of the Zend Framework:
http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-12409 (maybe do an upvote?)

Answer (score 9):

with ZF 1.12.3 the workaround is to pass consumerKey and consumerSecret in oauthOptions option, not directrly in the options.

```
        $options = array(
            'username' => /*...*/,
            'accessToken' => /*...*/,
            'oauthOptions' => array(
                'consumerKey' => /*...*/,
                'consumerSecret' => /*...*/,
            )
        );
```

Comment: There is also a change in calling the status update function. `status` has been changed to `statuses`, `$twitter->statuses->update('...')`

Answer (score 1):

While you wait to fix this issue in Zend_Twitter_Service component, you can do this workaround:

You need to send *customerKey* and *customerSecret* to Zend_Service_Twitter

```
$twitter = new Zend_Service_Twitter(array(
                'consumerKey' => $this->consumer_key,
                'consumerSecret' => $this->consumer_secret,
                'username' => $user->screenName,
                'accessToken' => unserialize($user->token)
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Today I have the same problem - Zend Framework works with API 1.

I created new class like

```
class Zend_Service_Twitter11 extends Zend_Service_Twitter
```

And override functions, which I need.

```
statusUpdate
statusReplies
```

etc

Comment: That's not a very descriptive class name. And shouldn't it be in a different namespace if Zend didn't write it? I realise it's just tweaks but it's good practice to use a different namespace if you override a class.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $this->_session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('auth_twitter');
    $config = Zend_Registry::get('config')->twitter->toArray();
    $access_tokenSession = unserialize($this->_session->access_token);



    $accessToken = new Zend_Oauth_Token_Access();
    $accessToken->setToken($access_tokenSession->oauth_token);
    $accessToken->setTokenSecret($access_tokenSession->oauth_token_secret);

    $temp = array();
    $temp['oauthOptions']['consumerKey'] = $config['consumerKey'];
    $temp['oauthOptions']['consumerSecret'] = $config['consumerSecret'];
    $temp['accessToken'] = $accessToken;
    $temp['username'] = $access_tokenSession->screen_name;


    $this->_twitter = new Zend_Service_Twitter($temp, null);

    $this->_twitter->account->accountVerifyCredentials()->toValue()
```