# Twitter API returns error 215, Bad Authentication Data

Tags: php, api, twitter

I am trying to call following Twitter's API to get a list of followers for a user.

http://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=username

And I am getting this error message in response.

```
{
    code = 215;
    message = "Bad Authentication data";
}
```

I can't seem to find the documentation related to this error code. Anyone has any idea about this error?

Comment: A lot of us are in the same boat.  Were you able to resolve this?  I'd love to see a solution for 1.1 since 1.0 is being deprecated.

Comment: Unfortunately I've still not been able to find a suitable solution. I am working on version 1 for now. But I will definitely post it here when I do. And if you get it before that, please do share...

Comment: Has anyone noticed on the Twitter oauth tool that a URL is generated with "/1.1" in it, but the cURL command says "oauth_version=1.0"? https://dev.twitter.com/apps/XXXXXX/oauth?nid=10364

Comment: @systemblogger Well, OAuth version and twitter API version is not the same thing. As for OAuth, there is 1.0 and 2.0 atm, and I am glad Twitter still uses 1.0.

Comment: Here first every one need to use oauth2/token api then use followers/list api. Other wise you will get this error. Because followers/list api requires  Authentication.  In Swift follow this link , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12053159/want-to-display-friends-list-from-twitter-into-iphone-app/54838586#54838586

Answer (score 27):

A very concise code without any other php file include of oauth etc.
Please note to obtain following keys you need to sign up with https://dev.twitter.com and create application.

```
<?php
$token = 'YOUR_TOKEN';
$token_secret = 'YOUR_TOKEN_SECRET';
$consumer_key = 'CONSUMER_KEY';
$consumer_secret = 'CONSUMER_SECRET';

$host = 'api.twitter.com';
$method = 'GET';
$path = '/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json'; // api call path

$query = array( // query parameters
    'screen_name' => 'twitterapi',
    'count' => '5'
);

$oauth = array(
    'oauth_consumer_key' => $consumer_key,
    'oauth_token' => $token,
    'oauth_nonce' => (string)mt_rand(), // a stronger nonce is recommended
    'oauth_timestamp' => time(),
    'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
    'oauth_version' => '1.0'
);

$oauth = array_map("rawurlencode", $oauth); // must be encoded before sorting
$query = array_map("rawurlencode", $query);

$arr = array_merge($oauth, $query); // combine the values THEN sort

asort($arr); // secondary sort (value)
ksort($arr); // primary sort (key)

// http_build_query automatically encodes, but our parameters
// are already encoded, and must be by this point, so we undo
// the encoding step
$querystring = urldecode(http_build_query($arr, '', '&'));

$url = "https://$host$path";

// mash everything together for the text to hash
$base_string = $method."&".rawurlencode($url)."&".rawurlencode($querystring);

// same with the key
$key = rawurlencode($consumer_secret)."&".rawurlencode($token_secret);

// generate the hash
$signature = rawurlencode(base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $base_string, $key, true)));

// this time we're using a normal GET query, and we're only encoding the query params
// (without the oauth params)
$url .= "?".http_build_query($query);
$url=str_replace("&amp;","&",$url); //Patch by @Frewuill

$oauth['oauth_signature'] = $signature; // don't want to abandon all that work!
ksort($oauth); // probably not necessary, but twitter's demo does it

// also not necessary, but twitter's demo does this too
function add_quotes($str) { return '"'.$str.'"'; }
$oauth = array_map("add_quotes", $oauth);

// this is the full value of the Authorization line
$auth = "OAuth " . urldecode(http_build_query($oauth, '', ', '));

// if you're doing post, you need to skip the GET building above
// and instead supply query parameters to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS
$options = array( CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("Authorization: $auth"),
                  //CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postfields,
                  CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
                  CURLOPT_URL => $url,
                  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false);

// do our business
$feed = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($feed, $options);
$json = curl_exec($feed);
curl_close($feed);

$twitter_data = json_decode($json);


foreach ($twitter_data as &$value) {
   $tweetout .= preg_replace("/(http:\/\/|(www\.))(([^\s<]{4,68})[^\s<]*)/", '<a href="http://$2$3" target="_blank">$1$2$4</a>', $value->text);
   $tweetout = preg_replace("/@(\w+)/", "<a href=\"http://www.twitter.com/\\1\" target=\"_blank\">@\\1</a>", $tweetout);
   $tweetout = preg_replace("/#(\w+)/", "<a href=\"http://search.twitter.com/search?q=\\1\" target=\"_blank\">#\\1</a>", $tweetout);
}

echo $tweetout;

?>
```

Regards

Comment: This works because of "CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER = false". We have traced down that it is cURL SSL certificate verification error, that makes Twitter library always return empty response.

Answer (score 11):

The only solution I've found so far is:

- Create application in twitter developer panel
- Authorize user with your application (or your application in user account) and save "oauth_token" and "oauth_token_secret" which Twitter gives you. Use [TwitterOAuth](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth) library for this, it's pretty easy, see examples coming with library.
- Using this tokens you can make authenticated requests on behalf of user. You can do it with the same library.

  ```
  // Arguments 1 and 2 - your application static tokens, 2 and 3 - user tokens, received from Twitter during authentification  
  $connection = new TwitterOAuth(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET, $tokens['oauth_token'], $tokens['oauth_token_secret']);  
  $connection->host = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/'; // By default library uses API version 1.  
  $friendsJson = $connection->get('/friends/ids.json?cursor=-1&user_id=34342323');
  ```

This will return you list of user's friends.

Answer (score 7):

FOUND A SOLUTION - using the [Abraham TwitterOAuth library](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/blob/master/README.md). If you are using an older implementation, the following lines should be added after the new TwitterOAuth object is instantiated:

```
$connection->host = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/";
$connection->ssl_verifypeer = TRUE;
$connection->content_type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
```

The first 2 lines are now documented in Abraham library Readme file, but the 3rd one is not. Also make sure that your oauth_version is still 1.0.

Here is my code for getting all user data from 'users/show' with a newly authenticated user and returning the user full name and user icon with 1.1 - the following code is implemented in the authentication callback file:

```
session_start();
require ('twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php');
require ('twitteroauth/config.php');

$consumer_key = '****************';
$consumer_secret = '**********************************';

$to = new TwitterOAuth($consumer_key, $consumer_secret);

$tok = $to->getRequestToken('http://exampleredirect.com?twitoa=1');

$token = $tok['oauth_token'];
$secret = $tok['oauth_token_secret'];

//save tokens to session
$_SESSION['ttok'] = $token;
$_SESSION['tsec'] = $secret;

$request_link = $to->getAuthorizeURL($token,TRUE);

header('Location: ' . $request_link);
```

The following code then is in the redirect after authentication and token request

```
if($_REQUEST['twitoa']==1){
    require ('twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php');
    require_once('twitteroauth/config.php');
    //Twitter Creds
    $consumer_key = '*****************';
    $consumer_secret = '************************************';

    $oauth_token = $_GET['oauth_token']; //ex Request vals->http://domain.com/twitter_callback.php?oauth_token=MQZFhVRAP6jjsJdTunRYPXoPFzsXXKK0mQS3SxhNXZI&oauth_verifier=A5tYHnAsbxf3DBinZ1dZEj0hPgVdQ6vvjBJYg5UdJI

    $ttok = $_SESSION['ttok'];
    $tsec = $_SESSION['tsec'];

    $to = new TwitterOAuth($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $ttok, $tsec);
    $tok = $to->getAccessToken();
    $btok = $tok['oauth_token'];
    $bsec = $tok['oauth_token_secret'];
    $twit_u_id = $tok['user_id'];
    $twit_screen_name = $tok['screen_name'];

    //Twitter 1.1 DEBUG
    //print_r($tok);
    //echo '<br/><br/>';
    //print_r($to);
    //echo '<br/><br/>';
    //echo $btok . '<br/><br/>';
    //echo $bsec . '<br/><br/>';
    //echo $twit_u_id . '<br/><br/>';
    //echo $twit_screen_name . '<br/><br/>';

    $twit_screen_name=urlencode($twit_screen_name);
    $connection = new TwitterOAuth($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $btok, $bsec);
    $connection->host = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/";
    $connection->ssl_verifypeer = TRUE;
    $connection->content_type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
    $ucontent = $connection->get('users/show', array('screen_name' => $twit_screen_name));

    //echo 'connection:<br/><br/>';
    //print_r($connection);
    //echo '<br/><br/>';
    //print_r($ucontent);

    $t_user_name = $ucontent->name;
    $t_user_icon = $ucontent->profile_image_url;

    //echo $t_user_name.'<br/><br/>';
    //echo $t_user_icon.'<br/><br/>';
}
```

It took me way too long to figure this one out. Hope this helps someone!!

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE:**
Twitter API 1 is now deprecated. Refer to above answer.

Twitter 1.1 does not work with that syntax (when I wrote this answer). Needs to be 1, not 1.1. This will work:

http://api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=username

Comment: Yeah that's correct. But that's because Twitter's Documentation suggested me to do so. (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/followers/ids). They said that version 1 is deprecated and I need to move to 1.1. Version 1 works for sure for this web service. But I was confused why 1.1 isn't working for me?

Comment: Version 1 will be deprecated in 6 months counting from march 2013 so I'd go for version 1.1

Comment: Testing different OAuth libraries I stick to [Twitter Async](https://github.com/jmathai/twitter-async), just changing this line `protected $apiVersion     = '1.1';` in file EpiTwitter.php works fine for Twitter API version 1.1

Comment: Twitter API 1 is deprecated

Comment: The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.

Answer (score 5):

The answer by Gruik worked for me in the below thread.

{Excerpt | [Zend_Service_Twitter - Make API v1.1 ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12677004/zend-service-twitter-make-api-v1-1-ready/16002174#16002174)}

> with ZF 1.12.3 the workaround is to pass consumerKey and consumerSecret in oauthOptions option, not directrly in the options.

```
    $options = array(
        'username' => /*...*/,
        'accessToken' => /*...*/,
        'oauthOptions' => array(
            'consumerKey' => /*...*/,
            'consumerSecret' => /*...*/,
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 4):

The url with `/1.1/` in it is correct, it is the new Twitter API Version 1.1.

But you need an application and authorize your application (and the user) using oAuth.

Read more about this on the [Twitter Developers documentation site](https://dev.twitter.com)
:)

Comment: Referencing a documentation site doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @moluv00 OP said: "I can't seem to find the documentation related to this error code."

Comment: Why did you post a general link. This is not an answer.

Answer (score 3):

You need to send *customerKey* and *customerSecret* to Zend_Service_Twitter

```
$twitter = new Zend_Service_Twitter(array(
                'consumerKey' => $this->consumer_key,
                'consumerSecret' => $this->consumer_secret,
                'username' => $user->screenName,
                'accessToken' => unserialize($user->token)
));
```

Answer (score 3):

After two days of research I finally found that to access s.o. public tweets you just need **any** application credentials, and not that particular user ones. So if you are developing for a client, you don't have to ask them to do anything.

**To use the new Twitter API 1.1 you need two things:**

- the [Abraham's TwitterOAuth library](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/tree/master/twitteroauth) that [Dante Cullari](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17250736/288808) already mentioned
- a brand new or already working application created via the [Twitter Developer site](https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new)

First, you can (actually have to) create an application with **your own** credentials and then get the *Access token* (OAUTH_TOKEN) and *Access token secret* (OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET) from the "**Your access token**" section.
Then you supply them in the constructor for the new TwitterOAuth object. Now you can access **anyone** public tweets.

```
$connection = new TwitterOAuth( CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET );

$connection->host = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/"; // change the default
$connection->ssl_verifypeer = TRUE;
$connection->content_type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';

$tweets = $connection->get('http://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name='.$username.'&count='.$count);
```

Actually I think this is what [Pavel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16578726/288808) has suggested also, but it is not so obvious from his answer.

Hope this saves someone else those two days :)

Answer (score 2):

This might help someone who use Zend_Oauth_Client to work with twitter api. This working config:

```
$accessToken = new Zend_Oauth_Token_Access();
$accessToken->setToken('accessToken');
$accessToken->setTokenSecret('accessTokenSecret');

$client = $accessToken->getHttpClient(array(
    'requestScheme' => Zend_Oauth::REQUEST_SCHEME_HEADER,
    'version' => '1.0', // it was 1.1 and I got 215 error.
    'signatureMethod' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
    'consumerKey' => 'foo',
    'consumerSecret' => 'bar',
    'requestTokenUrl' => 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token',
    'authorizeUrl' => 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize',
    'accessTokenUrl' => 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token',
    'timeout' => 30
));
```

It look like twitter api 1.0 allows oauth version to be 1.1 and 1.0, where twitter api 1.1 require only oauth version to be 1.0.

P.S We do not use Zend_Service_Twitter as it does not allow send custom params on status update.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you have read AND write access for application in twitter

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [HybridAuth](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/) and was running into this error connecting to Twitter. I tracked it down to (me) sending Twitter an incorrectly cased request type (get/post instead of GET/POST).

This would cause a 215:

```
$call = '/search/tweets.json';
$call_type = 'get';
$call_args = array(
    'q'           => 'pancakes',
    'count'       => 5,
);
$response = $provider_api->api( $call, $call_type, $call_args );
```

This would not:

```
$call = '/search/tweets.json';
$call_type = 'GET';
$call_args = array(
    'q'           => 'pancakes',
    'count'       => 5,
);
$response = $provider_api->api( $call, $call_type, $call_args );
```

Side note: In the case of HybridAuth the following also would not (because HA internally provides the correctly-cased value for the request type):

```
$call = '/search/tweets.json';
$call_args = array(
    'q'           => 'pancakes',
    'count'       => 5,
);
$response = $providers['Twitter']->get( $call, $call_args );
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem all the time the only solution I figurae out is typing `CONSUMER_KEY` and `CONSUMER_SECRET` directly to new TwitterOAuth class defination .

```
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(  "MY_CK" , "MY_CS"  );
```

Don't use variable or statics on this and see if the issue sloved .

Answer (score 0):

Here first every one need to use **oauth2/token api then use followers/list api**.
Other wise you will get this error. Because followers/list api requires  Authentication.

In swift (for mobile app) me also got the same problem.

If you want to know the api's and it's parameters follow this link , [Get twitter friends list in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54807221/get-twitter-friends-list-in-swift/54838712#54838712)

Answer (score -1):

I know that this is old but yesterday I faced the same issue when calling this URL using C# and the HttpClient class with the Bearer authentication token:

http://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=username

It turns out that the solution for me was to use HTTPS instead of HTTP. So my URL would look like this:

**https**://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=username

So here is a snippet of my code:

```
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer **** YOUR BEARER TOKEN GOES HERE ****");

                var response = client.GetAsync("statuses/user_timeline.json?count=10&screen_name=username").Result;
                if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    return result;
                }
                var items = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<dynamic>>().Result;
                foreach (dynamic item in items)
                {
                    //Do the needful
                }
            }
```

Comment: im getting `{"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]}`

Comment: @tq: Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12684765/twitter-api-returns-error-215-bad-authentication-data

Answer (score -1):

Try this twitter [API explorer](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/tools/console), you can sign in as a developer and query whatever you want.