# Twitter REST API: Bad Authentication Data (215)

Tags: ruby, twitter

I am trying to get tweets from Twitter to my Sinatra application. For that I am using REST API v1.0. It shows some functionality error so I am trying to migrate from v1.0 to v1.1. As a part of migration I am using the following code to get response:

```
response = http.request(Net::HTTP::Get.new("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=#{search_term}"))
```

but it shows some error like

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: The issue is that your authentication (OAuth?) isn't set up correctly. I can't help you further than that, but I suggest looking at other people's examples of setting up OAuth to pass through with your request.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12684765/twitter-api-returns-error-215-bad-authentication-data?rq=1

Comment: Thanks Jimbo. I configured Twitter configurations and added some new syntax for getting search item results like this.                                         Twitter.configure do |config|
  config.consumer_key = 'mykey'
  config.consumer_secret = 'my secret'
  config.oauth_token = 'oauth_token'
  config.oauth_token_secret = 'oauth_secret'
end                                                             tweets = Twitter.search("#{search_term}").results                    Now it is working fine.

Comment: @PJS Can u place the code of url how to add consumer key and consumer secret parameters??

Comment: @AvadhaniY here is the code                                        Twitter.configure do |config|
    config.consumer_key = 'your_consumer_key'
    config.consumer_secret = 'your_consumer_secret'
    config.oauth_token = 'your_oauth_token'
    config.oauth_token_secret = 'your_oauth_secret'
end                                                                  Thanks