# XMLHttpRequest is not working in QML Blackberry 10

Tags: javascript, qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

In the given code i have used one label and one button . i want that when i click on button a request must be sent which get the Json from the given link and print on label . but for this code i am just printing "OK" inside label upon success

The issue am facing is i am not getting into if statement. actually on Button clicked nothing happens. I know there is network manager in QT which i can use but in my situation i want to parse inside QML

```
// Default empty project template
import bb.cascades 1.0

// creates one page with a label

Page {
    Container {
        layout: StackLayout {}
        Label {
            id: msgLabel
            text: qsTr("Hello World")
            textStyle.base: SystemDefaults.TextStyles.BigText
            verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Center
            horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Center
        }
        Button {
            id: requestXML
            objectName: "requestXML"
            onClicked: {
                var doc = new XMLHttpRequest();
                doc.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (doc.readyState == 4) {
                        msgLabel.text="OK"
                        // pass “doc.responseText” to C++ for Parsing
                    }
                }
                doc.open("GET", "http://www.example.com/sample.json", true);
                doc.send();

            }
    }
    }
}
```

In my .pro file i have declared

```
CONFIG += qt warn_on cascades10
QT += network
CONFIG += debug
CONFIG += console
LIBS += -lbbdata
QT +=script
QT +=scripttools
```

Where i am wrong ? or i have to declare some thing else

Comment: asset:///main.qml:29: SyntaxError: Parse error; that is doc.open(...)

Comment: You are using old twitter API! `{"errors": [{"message": "The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.", "code": 68}]}`

Comment: @BojanKogoj here the issue is not with Twitter API. the main issue is i am not getting any response from any JSON link

Comment: Well look at my answer, it works.

Comment: I'd also suggest to have a look at [QTweetLib](https://github.com/blackberry/QTweetLib) which is encapsulated in a Cascades™ for BlackBerry 10 project and supports v1.1 Twitter API

Comment: @Sunseeker Here the main issue is not with Twitter API the main issue is XMLHttpRequest is not giving any response for any link

Comment: @IQworldMaster that's okay. I've been just thinking that you want to work with Twitter API at the of the day thus suggesting reusing an existing solution in case you didn't come across it yet. If Twitter API is simply an example for utilising `JSON`/`XMLHttpRequest` functionality is has nothing do with it then. Anyway, check my answer in respect to what might cause problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I don't have access to Twitter API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12684765/twitter-api-returns-error-215-bad-authentication-data), so I can't test it properly for you. But this does work for other JSON files. For this example you only need **LIBS += -lbbdata** in your .pro file. Also, read [DataSource](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__data__datasource.html) and [JsonDataAccess](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__data__jsondataaccess.html). If I were you I would download JSON through c++.

```
import bb.cascades 1.0
import bb.data 1.0

Page {
    Container {
        layout: StackLayout {
        }
        Label {
            id: msgLabel
            text: qsTr("Hello World")
            textStyle.base: SystemDefaults.TextStyles.BigText
            verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Center
            horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Center
        }
        Button {
            id: requestXML
            onClicked: {
                dataSource.load();
            }
        }
        attachedObjects: [
            DataSource {
                id: dataSource
                source: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=ladygaga"
                type: DataSourceType.Json

                onDataLoaded: {
                    console.log("loaded");
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); //just for testing
                    console.log(data);          
                }
                onError: {
                    console.log(errorType);
                    console.log(errorMessage);
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

Also the Twitter API you were using is no longer available so check [REST API v1.1 Resources](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1) or you will get the following error:

```
{"errors": [{"message": "The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.", "code": 68}]}
```

Comment: Great this is working . but can i ask what is the issue with my code.

Comment: I don't know, maybe it's not supported.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is in the cross-domain request which isn't allowed by default. In `WebWorks` you'd need to declare an `<access>` element in your application [config.xml](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/config_doc_elements.html) file for the domain(s) you wish to access.

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to do the same in a native `QML` project. Existing elements in `bar-descriptor.xml` don't allow to do the similar thing.

**ADDED:**

I wrote a simple HTTP stub for testing that guessing and looks like that's indeed what causes problems:

```
$ echo -e 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n' | nc -l 8080


GET /user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=ladygaga HTTP/1.1
CONTENT-TYPE: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Accept-Language: en-GB,*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
Host: 192.168.1.106:8080
```

I get `XMLHttpRequest.status == 200`in this case whilst on accessing Twitter endpoint I get `XMLHttpRequest.status == 0` for the same code:

```
import bb.cascades 1.0

Page {
    Container {
        layout: StackLayout {
        }
        Label {
            id: msgLabel
            text: qsTr("Hello World")
            textStyle.base: SystemDefaults.TextStyles.BigText
            verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Center
            horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Center
        }
        Button {
            id: requestXML
            objectName: "requestXML"
            onClicked: {
                sendRequest();
            }
        }
    }

    function sendRequest() {
        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (ajax.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                console.log("ajax.status: " + ajax.status);
                if (ajax.status === 200) {
                    console.log("Response = " + ajax.responseText);
                } else {
                    // This is very handy for finding out why your web service won't talk to you
                    console.log("Status: " + ajax.status + ", Status Text: " + ajax.statusText);
                }
            }
        }
//        var url = "http://192.168.1.106:8080/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=ladygaga";
        var url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=ladygaga";
        ajax.open("GET", url, true); // only async supported
        ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
        ajax.send();
    }
}
```