# How to recover tweet feed

Tags: javascript, json, tweets

I used this url to recover the tweet feed:

```
 http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/XXXX.json?callback=twitterCallback2&count=10
```

but I have this error:

```
{"errors": [{"message": "The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.", "code": 68}]}
```

Somebody can help me!!!

Comment: The error message says exactly what needs to happen, you need to transition to the new version of the Twitter API. You can read more about it at https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview. One of the big things that is new in 1.1 is required authentication for all requests, so be ready to implement oauth.

Comment: What part of the error don't you understand?

Answer (score 0):

The API that is supported is at that URL:

http://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline/XXXX.json?callback=twitterCallback2&count=10

**UPDATE**

I invite you to check this thread, this looks like the same problem as yours
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13416966/1683636

Comment: But now I have this: twittercallback1({"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]});

Comment: @Kory: You need to learn how to use that API and implement authentication.

Answer (score 0):

The Twitter API v1.0 has been discontinued a bit more than two months ago - you are now only able to use version 1.1 of the API:

https://dev.twitter.com/blog/api-v1-is-retired

One of the major changes is that every call now has to be authenticated, which means that even if you simply change to the same URL on API v1.1, you'll have a problem:

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline/XXXX.json?callback=twitterCallback2&count=10

You can find the documentation here:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1