# Twitter feed request url bad request in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter, twitter-feed

I am trying to get the feeds from the twitter using below url

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=manjunath00789&count=4
```

**Calling Code**

```
$tweets = wp_remote_get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=manjunath00789&count=4/");
        var_dump($tweets);
```

It is giving error

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]}
```

I had search on google but i could not found the solution.Can any body help to sort out the problem

Comment: Can you post your calling code ?

Comment: See [version 1.1](http://css.dzone.com/articles/using-new-twitter-api-v11) example posted for wordpress. You need OAUTH key & an access token for 1.1 api call.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Twitter API returns error 215, Bad Authentication Data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12684765/twitter-api-returns-error-215-bad-authentication-data)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to authenticate your app via oAuth.  You can use [this library](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth)

Comment: Brandon can you post a small example

Comment: See this thread- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12684765/twitter-api-returns-error-215-bad-authentication-data

Answer (score 0):

You need to be authenticated to fetch tweets. There is a [library](http://jasonmayes.com/projects/twitterApi/#sthash.vnnL3TvR.dpbs) in JavaScript to fetch tweets without authentication.