# username search with twitter api with partial string

Tags: php, twitter

I am new to Twitter Api and want to use it to make username search. Simply let's say I search for "john" and I would like to have as results john, johnas, johnathan, john1980,…and so on. I've tried to use the user/search but it does not give me what I've described. I think I need the correct way to  write the search query using wildcard understandable from Twitter api. I am using php code getting inspired from "A Bright Worker" in [Twitter API returns error 215, Bad Authentication Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12684765/twitter-api-returns-error-215-bad-authentication-data). Please is there somebody with some hints ?

Comment: Are you able to retrieve any other data from Twitter? What happens if you try to call your timeline? I'm trying to establish if you are authenticated correctly.

Comment: @Terence Eden. Yes I am able to retrieve the data correctly. My problem is how to configure parameters or which resource of the api I should use. I've used https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/search.json. For example if I pass in q parameter the string "ruruccio" I receive as result 2 users, having as  screenname "MauroRuruccio" and "ruruccio" but I don't receive the user having screenname "mastroruruccio".