# Get tweets using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter, oauth

I am trying to make an app with material design and angularjs to get the tweets using hashtag search.

```
getTweets: function(hashtag, since,$http) {
                    var cfg = {};
                    var paramSince = since ? '&since_id='+ since : '';
                    var queryUrl = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23'+hashtag+paramSince;
                   // var queryUrl = '/search?hashtag='+hashtag+paramSince;
                    var promise = $http.get(queryUrl, cfg).then(function (response) {                        
                        return response;
                    });
                    return promise;
        }
```

This  API returns error 215, Bad Authentication Data

Here is the full [`application`](http://plnkr.co/edit/8njQKULmXQ8dvHhemS1M?p=preview)

**STEPS TO REPRODUCE:**

(i) Click Add Account

(ii)Login

(iii) Click finish

Comment: possible duplicate of [Twitter API returns error 215, Bad Authentication Data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12684765/twitter-api-returns-error-215-bad-authentication-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$http` is undefined. You injected `$http` service into your `twitterApp.services` factory, then you (try) redeclared it inside the returned function `getTweets`.
In this case there is no "magic", you call `getTweets` with two arguments, so `$http` becomes undefined. The solution is removing this parameter from `getTweets` and use `$http` as a closure.

**UPDATE:**
There's no error handling in the process, you have to `reject` the promise when error occurs. This way you can also see the error comes from the server.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Lbb6EvwsjuecmFn5Vchd?p=preview

As you can see on the console, when trying to get connected, the server returns an origin error:

> Error: Origin "http://run.plnkr.co/Of0F9UHpjhrqkjdw/" does not match
>   any registered domain/url on oauth.io(…)

It's probably about settings in your server (in this case, oauth.io) in terms of CORS.

Comment: thanks, but why does the twitter api returns bad authentication?

Comment: Check your twitter URL